# Permission denied when starting Minikube on macOS

Tags: macos, docker, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to start minikube cluster on my macOS but i get always "Permission denied"

> (base) MacBook-Pro-de-..:desktop ..$ minikube start
>      -bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: Permission denied

What i should do ?

Comment: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/minikube`

Comment: E0301 15:19:14.198136   48335 start.go:268] Error setting up kubeconfig:  Error reading file "/../.kube/config": open /../.kube/config: not a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute following commands to add permissions to files:

```
$ chmod ugo+rwx ~/.kube/config
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.kube
$ chmod +x your-minikube-localization
```

Configure proxy:

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,$(minikube ip)
export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy,$(minikube ip)
```

Then run minikube command taking proxy under consideration (IPs set below are just example):

```
$ minikube start --alsologtostderr --kubernetes-version v1.13.1 --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://10.0.2.2:1087 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.0.2.2:1087 --docker-env NO_PROXY=10.0.2.2,192.168.99.100


$ minikube start --alsologtostderr --kubernetes-version v1.13.2 --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://10.0.2.2:3128 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.0.2.2:3128 --docker-env NO_PROXY=10.0.2.2,192.168.99.100
```

In this case proxy configuration:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

**Please must remember to add your minikube IP to NO_PROXY.**

Similar problems you can find here: [file-permission](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5714), [kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4100).

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider upvote/accept it, it will be useful for community.

Answer (score 0):

I got now this Error:

Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
E0301 15:19:14.198136   48335 start.go:268] Error setting up kubeconfig:  Error reading file "/../.kube/config": open /../.kube/config: not a directory
E0301 15:19:15.128758   48335 util.go:151] Error uploading error message: Error sending error report to https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/k8s-minikube/events:report?key=AIzaSyACUwzG0dEPcl-eOgpDKnyKoUFgHdfoFuA, got response code 400

Answer (score 0):

it happens when you dont have sudo rights. type sudo minikube start or switch as a root user and then start minikube by "minukube start" it worked for me if youre on linux